# How to access ItemId in controller in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I declared contain in main view. So how to access in controller. Here i have **democontainer** and **demopanel**. so how to access it.

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
      extend: 'Ext.Panel',
      alias: 'widget.mainpage',


      config: {
        width: 710,
        margin: '10px auto 0',
        itemId: 'democontainer',
        layout: {
          type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [
        {
          xtype:'container',
          cls:'wholeMenuWrap',
          margin: '65px 0 0 0',
          width: 175,

          items:[ 
....and
 {
    xtype: 'homepage',
    cls:'homepage-wrap',
    itemId: 'demopanel',
    layout: {
      type: 'fit'
    }
  },
  {
    xtype:'container',
    layout: 'vbox',
    margin: '65px 0 0 0',

    width: 185,
    items:[
    {
      xtype: 'titlebar',          
      cls:'roundedToolbar',
```

I want to access on controller like this, but i am unable to access it.

```
    config: {
        main:this,
        profile: Ext.os.deviceType.toLowerCase(),

       refs:{
       myContainer: 'mainpage',
       },
        control: {
          'mainpage': {
            activate: 'onActivate',
            itemtap: 'onItemTap',
            },
'mainpage textfield[itemId=searchBox]' : {
//clear the input text box
clearicontap : 'onClearSearch',
//on every key stroke
keyup: 'onSearchKeyUp'
},
```

........

```
   onSearchKeyUp: function(searchField) {
   var container = this.up('#democontainer');
          var panel = container.down('#demopanel');
          panel.removeInnerAt(0);
          var submitWordBySearch = { xtype: 'searchplusfav' }; 
          panel.insert(0, submitWordBySearch);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'up'
```

anyone please help me out.

***I added New Code:***

```
    refs:{

         myContainer: 'mainpage',
         demoContainer2: '#democontainer', //same as demoContainer1
         demoContainer3:'#demopanel'
       },

...-------------
  onSearchKeyUp: function(searchField) {
 var container = this.getDemoContainer2();
           var panel = container.getDemoContainer3();
          panel.removeInnerAt(0);
          var submitWordBySearch = { xtype: 'searchplusfav' }; 
          panel.insert(0, submitWordBySearch);
```

**Getting error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'demoContainer2'
```

**Working code:**

```
  onKeySubmitTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) 
  {
    var container = dataview.up('#democontainer');
    var panel = container.down('#demopanel');
    panel.removeInnerAt(0);
    var submitWordBySearch = { xtype: 'categorywordsdisplay' }; 
    panel.insert(0, submitWordBySearch);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add this for my own problem, which is exact work:

```
 var container = Ext.Viewport.up('#democontainer');
  var panel = Ext.Viewport.down('#demopanel');
  panel.removeInnerAt(0);
  var submitWordBySearch = { xtype: 'submitnewdefinitionholder' }; 
  panel.insert(0, submitWordBySearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.up()` within a controller will not really do anything.  To get a reference to democontainer, you first should realize that declaring an `itemId` in the `config` of a class is kind of useless; this should really be done when declaring a class instance.  You essentially already have a reference to `#democontainer` because these 2 are equivalent with your current class config:

```
refs: {
    demoContainer1: 'mainpage',
    demoContainer2: '#democontainer' //same as demoContainer1
}
```

So, using the `ref` that you already have, to get that reference later in the controller, all you need to use is `this.getMyContainer()`:

```
refs: {
    myContainer: 'mainpage',
},
....
onSearchKeyUp: function(field) {
    var container = this.getMyContainer();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i am unable set in to  panel.removeInnerAt(0);
          var submitWordBySearch = { xtype: 'searchplusfav' }; 
          panel.insert(0, submitWordBySearch);...Please watch my edited question.

Comment: ok, Thank you, but i am still getting these type of error.Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getDemoContainer2' AutoSearchFinal.js?_dc=1376568704064:235
(anonymous function) AutoSearchFinal.js?_dc=1376568704064:235
show.fn